# New thread in ASP.NET runs in different culture

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, timer, globalization, culture

I have System.Timers.Timer that performs some operations based on schedule. When timer rises event, the threads culture is 'ru-RU' differ from culture in my web config.

```
<globalization culture="en-US" uiCulture="en-US" requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" />
```

I guess the culture in timer handler based on my regional settings which is ru-RU.
Currently i set it manually to 'en-US' in timer handler, but i think this is not the best way to solve the problem.

In any case is there another solution to have the same culture in another thread as in my web config except setting it manually?

Answer (score 0):

That is very strange. Every thread that creates another thread will pass on all the context including security and locale.

Add a debug code to check the `Culture` and `UICulture` of the `Thread.CurrentThread` at the time of creation of thread.

Comment: its timer handler and it runs in separate thread. In this handler the culture is differ from config

Comment: Well, there's you problem then!